# Why is BalanceRemaining not updating after ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

I am reporting the storemanaged consumable(s) (I put them in my account with a code in the store) to be consumed like this:

```
foreach (Scan Scan in Export)
{
    StoreConsumableResult result = await context.ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync("StoreIDofMyConsumable", Convert.ToUInt32(1), new Guid());
    if(result.Status != StoreConsumableStatus.Succeeded)
    {
        NoError = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm getting back as `result.Status` Succeeded.

But `result.BalanceRemaining` is not different to the value it was before the report.
Also, if I do

```
StoreConsumableResult singles = await context.GetConsumableBalanceRemainingAsync("StoreIDofMyConsumable");
```

afterweards and check `singles.BalanceRemaining` it's the same as before.

I thought, that if I report a consumable as consumed, it will disappear from the balance.

Please tell me, how I can make this working.

Thank You!

Comment: You said you report the Store-managed consumable. Please check if you select the "Store-managed" option when you create the add-on. Because if you select the "Developer-managed" option, you would need to write code to update it by yourself.

Comment: Hi,
the Consumable is Store-Managed.

Comment: If it's Store-managed, this issue is very strange. I still hope that you could check your windows dashboard again to see if the `Store ID` that you use in your code is Store-managed add-on's Store ID.